# How to run `Model.objects.values()` with command-line option?

Tags: python, django

In Django, I'm making a `manage.py` command called `some_command`.

Here's what I have in `management/commands/some_command.py` so far.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
  def add_arguments(self,parser):
    parser.add_argument(
        "--fields",
        dest="fields",
        required=True,
        help="Fields to query; Enter in pipe-delimited format",
    )

  def handle(self, *args, **options):
    Model=      apps.get_model(app_label="my_app", model_name="MyModelName")
    print Model.objects.values(tpl(fields.split('|')))
```

This gives me the error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`.

The option `fields` is a string of columns I want to query, delimited by the pipe character. So it will look something like "col1|col2". How do I query just those fields via this custom Django command line process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use argument [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) here.Change your last line to

```
print Model.objects.values(*options['fields'].split('|'))
```

Please note that you need to properly quote your commandline arguements as pipe charactor have special meaning in terminal.

> python manage.py yourcommand --fields="col1|col2"